# What is the optimized way to handle base encodings in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, binary

context : I'm currently using Haskell to develop functions that handle multiple base encodings (base2,base8... up to base64) with a lot of different options (pad/nopad, upper/lower, different versions of base encodings) It could potentially be used to encode data transmitted through a p2p network so it should be optimized and easy to maintain )

problem: my functions handle the actual encoding with lists of 0 or 1 Ints that are a subsitute for binary data ( [0,1,0,0,1]  represents 01001).

So the code works but using lists of ints like that seems awfully clunky and "shortcutty" to me.

question: Using Haskell, when dealing with precise handling of binary data (specifically in the base encoding context) is there a better and faster type to use than the one stated above?

Comment: Use bytestring for packed binary data.  There is already base16, base58 and base64.  A generalized `baseN` with customizable alphabet would be a great package to build and contribute to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right @Thomas M DuBuisson gave a good answer. I am going to use the ByteString type, which is more efficient for this type of program and will allow me to perform precise bitwise operations on Word8 terms if needed.

Comment: It's good that you answer your own question and also ok to use information from a comment, but if you do that please make sure it actually answers the original question. I.e., write out briefly what your solution is now.